# Error: The application does not have a valid signature - Command Line Building IPA File

Tags: ios, mobile, build, xcrun

The build line:

xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v Myapp.app -o Myapp.ipa --sign The Hash of my Signing Identity goes here --embed MyProvisioningProfile.mobileprovision

It compiles into an IPA file, but when I try to transfer it to my device I get a "The application does not have a valid signature" error.

If I use that Certificate and that Mobile Provision in the XCode UI it works perfectly. I am unsure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the .app file was packaged, a .xcodeproj file was passed into the xcodebuild command to build from. A setting in that xcodeproj file was set to use a Developer Certificate rather than a Distribution certificate. Opening the XCode UI and changing all references from iOS Developer to iOS Distribution fixed the issue.